# How do I figure out which textbox is connected to which record in a Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I figured out how to get the values from a repeater control, but how do I get the record id for the row that contains the textbox.
My repeater is databound to a dataset that contains purchase orders that have backorders remaining. Here is the markup for my repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 124px">Purchase Order :</td>
                        <td style="width: 124px"><asp:Label ID="lblPONumber" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Product
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            BackOrder
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Received
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 124px"><%# Eval("ProductName")%></td>
                        <td style="width: 124px"><%# Eval("OnBackOrderAmount") %></td>
                        <td style="width: 124px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <hr />
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and I have a button on the outside of the repeater that gets the values from the textboxes, so I can update the database, and that code is

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            TextBox txtQty = (TextBox)rptItem.FindControl("txtQty");
            if(txtQty != null)
            { 
                Response.Write(txtQty.Text); 
            }
        }
```

The response.write is just so I could see that it was working instead of stepping through the code. As you can see in the repeater that each line has a product name, the quantity on backorder, and a textbox to enter in the received amount to update the database. That's where the problem lies, how do I know which textbox is for which record? so I can update the database

**Edit**

I changed some code around and came up with this

Markup

```
<td><asp:Label ID="hdnField" runat="server"><%# Eval("ProductID") %></asp:Label></td>
```

CodeBehind, added to the foreach

```
Label hdn = (Label)rptItem.FindControl("hdnField");
            if(txtQty != null)
            {
                Response.Write(txtQty.Text + "    ProductID: " + hdn.Text.ToString() + "<br>"); 
            }
```

When click on the button that runs the statement, I can get the textbox values but not the label text at that has the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `HiddenField` in the `ItemTemplate` containing the Id needed from the database.
As you get the quantity (in your foreach loop), get the `HiddenField` value and make your database call.

Comment: I tried using a hiddenfield but it kept throwing an error, so I used a label and added it so I could view the productid and it worked fine, then I also changed the bit of code, which I am going to show in the edit.

Comment: I got the hiddenfield working, I was adding the Eval incorrectly. Thanks for the help